# Unable to extract coordinates from twitter API

Tags: python, api, export-to-csv, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Here is my code:

```
[import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time

#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

ckey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret = "xxxxxxxxxx"

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet\['tweetID'\] = \[tweet.id for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['tweetText'\] = \[tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['tweetRetweetCt'\] = \[tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['tweetFavoriteCt'\] = \[tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['tweetSource'\] = \[tweet.source for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['tweetCreated'\] = \[tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userID'\] = \[tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userScreen'\] = \[tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userName'\] = \[tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userCreateDt'\] = \[tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userDesc'\] = \[tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userFollowerCt'\] = \[tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userFriendsCt'\] = \[tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userLocation'\] = \[tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['userTimezone'\] = \[tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['Coordinates'\] = \[tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['GeoEnabled'\] = \[tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets\]
    DataSet\['Language'\] = \[tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets\]
    tweets_place= \[\]
    #users_retweeted = \[\]
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet\['TweetPlace'\] = \[i for i in tweets_place\]
    #DataSet\['UserWhoRetweeted'\] = \[i for i in users_retweeted\]

    return DataSet

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
#auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS\['consumer_key'\], OAUTH_KEYS\['consumer_secret'\])
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS\['consumer_key'\], OAUTH_KEYS\['consumer_secret'\])

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print ("Scraping data now") # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms  q='ganesh'
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="travel",since='2021-01-27',until='2021-01-28',lang='en',count=50)
    results=\[\]
    for item in cursor.items(1000): # Remove the limit to 1000
            results.append(item)


    DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
    DataSet.to_csv('Result.csv',index=False)
    print ("Completed.. !!")][1]
```

[image: [click here to see the output image.][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih67w.png]

I am trying to get Twitter data using API. For my study, I need coordinates of the tweet i.e. latitude and longitude. In the output, the coordinate is empty.

Can someone help me to solve this issue as I cannot proceed further without the lat long data.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: why do you have a "[" in your first import?

Comment: @jps it was a url but wasn’t clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The location object `coordinates` is provided but often empty, this is due to a change Twitter made some time ago.

You should instead rely on the [Place](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/geo#place) object which provides the name of the place the coordinates **if the user share** the location or add a place to the tweet.

```
'place': {'id': '07d9edfbc6085000', 
'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/07d9edfbc6085000.json',
'place_type': 'poi', 
'name': 'The place',
'country': 'The Netherlands', 
'bounding_box': 
   {'type': 'Polygon', '
     coordinates': [[[4.853216261144857, 52.36157762209008]
     etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But is there any other way we can get the latitude and longitude of tweets? Because I have to further put this data into GIS platform which mandatorily requires Coordinates data.

Comment: It doesn't seem so: Tweets must be get tagged by the user first, then they include the Place payload

Comment: @BeppeC Is  `coordinates` still available? I am interested in it but unfortunately all I get is bounding box. I am using `tweept.StreamingClient` with its `on_data()`. Sample results: `{'data':{..},.."includes": {
    "places": [
      {
        
        "geo": {
          "type": "Feature",
          "bbox": [
            7.7042185,
            10.5496647,
            9.4005112,
            12.6105891
          ],
          "properties": {}
        },
        "id": "013c94bf4d5073c9",
        "name": "Kano",
        "place_type": "admin"
      }
    ]
  }}`